# is int foo() { return foo(); } a recursive function?

Tags: c, function, recursion

Will:

```
int foo();

int foo()
{
    return foo();
}
```

loop permanently or it will run the function just twice (one implicitly and one at a time of terminating).

Comment: @Rizier123 I wouldn't ask if I've tried it.

Comment: @AlanSalios And did the program stopped ?

Comment: I am not able to interpret the happening anyway.

Comment: @AlanSalios Run it and put a breakpoint on `foo()` then debug through it.

Comment: No need to declare `foo` beforehand; it's in scope in its own body.

Comment: I am not quite sure how much of it I can test through android device.. but I'll define these downvotes as being based on the "Anti spoon-feeding" concept.

Comment: Well, I'm not surprised "I wouldn't ask if I'd tried" gets downvoted. If the question had been "I tried and got a segmentation fault although I expected X" perhaps would have been perceived differently (though that's still not a great question). On the other hand, I'm not sure this might be UB (in which case trying out may be useless): IIRC, the latest C++ standard says something along "the compiler may assume a thread without side-effects terminates" and C11 adopted the C++ memory model to standardize threading, maybe they're similar here... Either way, the function is useless :)

Comment: I don't know. I think this satisfies a lot of people's curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, foo() is a recursive function that results in an infinite loop.

If your compiler optimizes tail recursion, then it will likely chug along until you kill it.  If your compiler doesn't optimize tail recursion then you will eventually overflow your stack and/or run out of memory.

Comment: This sounds vile as well as dangerous.

Comment: @AlanSalios: The way you've written that recursive function is vile and dangerous.  Typically, a recursive function will have an exit condition (i.e. - don't recursively call itself again) that is somehow parameterized by its inputs so that infinite recursion cannot occur.  Lots of tree manipulation code is best written in a recursive manner.  A typical exit condition might be something like if (node->child != NULL) recurse(node->child);  Then when you build the tree you ensure that terminal nodes have their children as NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a recursive function without any base case. Hence it will never terminate normally.